# Any app for maintaining target list and daily to-do list?

Tags: webapp-rec, tasks

I would like to set myself weekly, monthly and yearly target lists for both my professional and personal life, so that I can track accomplishments with ease. I also want to track my list of things which I needed to do everyday.

Is there any best freely available web app for such a task?

I know Google Calendars provides an option of adding a task list but I'm looking for a much better available option.

Comment: Have you considered using Trello? I use it every day and love it.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the style and organization capabilities associated with [wunderlist](http://wunderlist.com).  In addition to keeping lists for Today, Tomorrow, 7 Days, and Someday you can add specific due dates and view tasks either in separate lists or all-in-one.

You can also star tasks, search tasks, reorder them, share them, and print them out.  I'll stop since I'm sounding a bit like a promotional ad (I'm not associated with wunderlist, I just really like it), I'll leave it at that.

Hope that does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/). It's easy to add items to a list and you can use keywords such as "Pick up mail on Monday" and it will make a task scheduled for Monday called "Pick up the Mail". It's pretty light weight and free. I believe the phone apps are not free though.